# Change Ctrl + Shift + C default terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

#### In Visual Studio Code on windows. The key binding Ctrl + Shift + C opens a new external terminal.

By default, this opens a cmd console. Is there a way to change this default terminal because I want to use git bash instead.

I do know that the command answers to the "ComSpec" environment variable, but changing this variable to the path of the git bash throws this [The console closes with the code 126](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ox3zu.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this setting:

```
Terminal > External: Windows Exec
```

with something like `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe` or wherever your git bash is installed.

That is for opening an external terminal.  For the integrated terminal within vscode, use:

```
Terminal > Integrated > Shell: Windows
```

with `"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Git\\\\bin\\\\bash.exe"`

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to open directly `Window Terminal`

```
where wt

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe
```